# $7^n | \binom{2016}{1003}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> $7^n | \binom{2016}{1003}$. Find the largest value of $n$.

I am a newbie in number theory. Only the thing I know about this is $$\binom{2016}{1003} = \frac{2016!}{1003! \times 1013!}$$
How to proceed ?

Comment: Hint: $7$ is prime.  How many factors of $7$ appear in $2016!$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, $n!= 7^x \times \{something\}$ then $x$ is given by [Legendre's_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula) -  $$L_7(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \big{\lfloor}\frac{n}{7^i} \big{\rfloor} $$
Now Let, $$\frac{2016!}{1003!\times 1013!} = \frac{7^a \times {C_1}}{7^b \times C_2 * 7^c \times C_3} = 7^{a-(b+c)} \times {something}$$
So, the largest power of $7$ = $L_7(2016) - L_7(1003) - L_7(1013)$
You will never need $7^4$ as $7^4 > 2016,1003,1013$. SO you can solve it in hand.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In base seven we have $2016=5610_7$, $1013=2645_7$ and $1003=2632_7$. So when you add $1003+1013$ in base seven there will be three carries (at positions 1,2,3). Therefore, by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), the answer is $7^3$.

Comment: WoW! Didn't hear about this before :) (y)

Comment: @RezwanArefin Kummer's theorem follows relatively easily from Legendre's formula that you refer to. It we have $n=\sum_{i\ge0} a_ip^i$ with $0\le a_i<p$, then Legendre gives
$$\nu_p(n!)=\frac 1{p-1}(n-\sum_{i\ge0}a_i).$$ Doing that for all the factorials in the binomial coefficient gives the result.

Comment: Yep. I Just read the wikipedia article :). Thanks :)

Comment: The leading terms of that cancel from $\nu_p\binom n k$. What remains is here $2+6+4+5=17$, $2+6+3+2=13$, $5+6+1+0=12$, and the highest power of $7$ dviding this binomial coefficient will be
$$\frac16(2016-12-1013+17-1003+13)=\frac{18}6=3.$$

Answer (score 0):

The exponent $v_p$ of a prime $p$ in a factorial $n!$ (i.e., the unique integer with $p^{v_p}\mid n!$ and $p^{v_p+1}\nmid n!$) can be found as
$$ v_p=\left\lfloor \frac np\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac n{p^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac n{p^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots$$
(where only finitely many summands need to be considered because $\left\lfloor \frac n{p^k}\right\rfloor=0$ as soon as $p^k>n$).